# Laravel jobs table keeps queues undeleted after doing the job

Tags: php, laravel, queue, laravel-5.1, laravel-forge

I'm using database queue driver of Laravel to send email in a production server (laravel forge digitalocean), the email is sent normally but the problem the queues stayed stored in the jobs table and the number increases and keeps attempting to 255
and I did in the listener class

```
if ($this->attempts() > 10) {
    $this->delete();
}
```

And nothing gets deleted. How do I remove them after the email is sent?

Answer (score 1):

You need to run

```
$this->delete();
```

always when job is done and not only when attempts number is greater than 10

Comment: I did it without attempts() function and nothing get deleted , I think the problem from forge , in vagrant homestead it get deleted automatically

Answer (score 1):

this is from the laravel docs

```
public function handle(SendEmail $command)
{ 
    if (true)
    {
        $this->release(30);
    }
}
```